# vscode with gitlens couldn't show the change of submodule in commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

When I want to see the change of submodule in vscode with gitlens, it reports this error:

```
The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: 
Command failed: /usr/bin/git -c core.quotepath=false -c color.ui=false -c log.showSignature=false 
show --textconv d7a875aedc5c70a56779455150a30ff1cd23bd10:./lib/pfcp 
-- fatal: bad object d7a875aedc5c70a56779455150a30ff1cd23bd10:./lib/pfcp
```

But I can see it in gitlab or git command：

```
Subproject commit f97e5a28313b13dc24d68a61e609254508df2db3
Subproject commit 118891491b31920e96d2fde1b8d5cb11cab0e60a
```